# Akeneo resizing asset variation keeps proportions

Tags: assets, akeneo

I use Akeneo 2.1.9 EE version.

I wrote a configuration file to generate asset variation for a specific channel, which sets width and length to 750px

```
asset_channel_configurations:
     ecommerce:
         configuration:
             resize:
                 width: 750
                 height: 750
```

But then when I generate variations for a rectangular image, it doesn't change to a square and keeps proportions with the width or height at 750px.

Why do I get this behavior ? Isn't `resize` supposed to not keep proportions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akeneo is using ImageMagick for asset variations. By default, the [resize](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) command does keep proportions. It is possible to [force Imagemagick to ignore it](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#noaspect). In this case you will have a square image, regardless of the original ratio. That means it would be distorted to fit the square aspect ratio, if the input was not square.

However, this is not possible in Akeneo. So you have two solutions:
- you can either [add a new transformation](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/manipulate_pim_data/product_asset/add_new_transformation.html#) that will resize without respecting the image ratio
- or you can override the existing Akeneo `resize` implementation (it is in the class `Akeneo\Component\FileTransformer\Transformation\Image\Resize`, in Enterprise Edition only) so it always ignores the ratio.